# Error 405 Method Not Allowed when sending a PUT AJAX request to PHP with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, http, put

I am just trying to implement a REST-like application with PHP + jQuery.

In the very first attempt I started getting this error

> PUT http://... 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I put this in the very first line of my PHP script

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/myscript.php',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(response) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

I did nothing special in terms of configuration. 
Why is my Ajax request getting rejected and how can I solve this?

Comment: Try using `get` instead of `put` and see if it works.

Comment: Try using `http://localhost/myscript.php` as the `url`

Comment: Maybe it is some misconfiguration..see this: http://serverfault.com/questions/148865/enable-put-method-on-apache-for-any-php-script

Comment: Put `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");`, also, is __`Access-Control-Allow-Orgin`__ a typo?

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/myscript.php',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(response) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

**To:**

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/myscript.php',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(response) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

**And:**

> Is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Not `Access-Control-Allow-Orgin`

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
```

**To:**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```